# pytest: refactor the repeated testcases

Tags: pytest, automated-refactoring

I have testcases like below:

```
class TestSomething():
    def test_a(self):
        ...
    def test_b(self):
        ...
```

It was working well. But now I have to change some environment setting, reboot the machine to make it effective, and re-test these cases again.

All I can think of is:

```
class TestSomething():
    def test_a(self):
        ...
    def test_b(self):
        ...
    # change the env var on the target machine and reboot it
    def test_change_env_and_reboot(self):
        some_env_var = get_env_var()
        if not some_env_var:
            set_env_var()
            reboot()
    def test_a1(self):
        self.test_a()
    def test_b1(self):
        self.test_b()
```

It doesn't look too good. Is there a better way to achieve the same purpose, without changing the original existing testcases?

**Update:**
The purpose is to detect `some_env_var`, set it and reboot the machine if it is not `True`. After that, re-run `test_a` and `test_b`. On the other hand, if `some_env_var` is already set, do not re-run these testcases.

Comment: First I would check if you really need to reboot the machine, or if you can just fake the changed environment instead. If that were possible, you could just derive a test class with a different setup. Apart from that, your approach won't work if you reboot the test machine (or is it another machine?)

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Yes, I can fake the change for the environment variable. How to derive a test class with a different setup? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just derive from your first test class and add a setup method (I used `setup_class` which is called once, if needed you could use `setup_method`, which is called before each test). If you run pytest with this file:

```
import os

class TestSomething:
    def test_a(self):
        pass

    def test_b(self):
        pass


class TestSomethingElse(TestSomething):
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        if os.getenv('VAR') == '1':
            pytest.skip("Test not needed")
        else:
            print('Changing configuration...')
```

You get:

```
collecting ... collected 4 items

test_setup.py::TestSomething::test_a PASSED                              [ 25%]
test_setup.py::TestSomething::test_b PASSED                              [ 50%]
test_setup.py::TestSomethingElse::test_a Changing configuration...
PASSED                          [ 75%]
test_setup.py::TestSomethingElse::test_b PASSED                          [100%]

========================== 4 passed in 0.07 seconds ===========================
```

As you can see, each test is run again after the changed setup has been executed.

If you don't need the test (here detected by the value of an environment variable), you can skip it directly in the setup. In this case your output would be:

```
collecting ... collected 4 items

test_setup.py::TestSomething::test_a PASSED                              [ 25%]
test_setup.py::TestSomething::test_b PASSED                              [ 50%]
test_setup.py::TestSomethingElse::test_a SKIPPED                         [ 75%]
Skipped: Test not needed

test_setup.py::TestSomethingElse::test_b SKIPPED                         [100%]
Skipped: Test not needed
```

Comment: Is there a way to tell the child class to skip the testcases in the parent class if the envrionment variable is already in effect?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - do you want no tests executed in this case? You could use `@pytest.skipif` on the class in this case.

Comment: Suppose `setup_class` returns `True` if the env is set, so the decorator for the child class would be `@pytest.mark.skipif(setup_class==True)`?

Comment: That will not work, as you don't have that information at load time. I'm still not sure what you want to achieve here - maybe you adapt your question or write a new one. I may have another look tomorrow.

Comment: I mean, by default, `TestSomethingElse` will inherit all the testcases from `TestSomething` and run them after `setup_class` (to detect and set the env var if necessary) is done. My purpose is, if the env variable is already set to the desired value, I'd like all the inherited testcases in `TestSomethingElse` from `TestSomething` to be skipped completely.

Comment: I added that in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, MrBean. That completed the circle. I didn't know `pytest.skip` could be used in the classmethod to skip all testcases in a test class. This is smart.